# Why python's 'bisect' module (binary search) does not allow use it with particular 'key'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-search

Quote from docs:

> https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html
>
> Unlike the sorted() function, it does not make sense for the bisect()
>   functions to have key or reversed arguments because that would lead to
>   an inefficient design (successive calls to bisect functions would not
>   “remember” all of the previous key lookups).
>
> Instead, it is better to search a list of precomputed keys to find the
>   index of the record in question:
>
> ```
> >>> data = [('red', 5), ('blue', 1), ('yellow', 8), ('black', 0)]
> >>> data.sort(key=lambda r: r[1])
> >>> keys = [r[1] for r in data]         # precomputed list of keys
> >>> data[bisect_left(keys, 0)]
> ('black', 0)
> ```

But suggested solution works for `O(N)` (creating list of keys), not for `O(logN)` (assuming there is a need to call bisect one time for one list).

Is there any built-in binary search, allowing search with a custom key?

(Except for overloading `operator __lt__()` for passed objects.)

And if no, then why python hasn't it? (assuming tagline "batteries included")

Comment: The tagline "batteries included" can't mean "every possible thing included", because there are infinite possible things

Answer (score 0):

There would either be an inconsistency in the parameters to `bisect` and `insort`, or you would have to pass a value, not a key, to search. Either way *someone* would be in for an unfortunate surprise.

That is, either

```
def insort(a, x, lo=0, hi=None, *, key=None):
    lo = bisect(a, x, lo, hi, key)
    a.insert(lo, x)

def bisect(a, x, lo=0, hi=None, *, key=None):
    if lo < 0:
        raise ValueError('lo must be non-negative')
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(a)
    if key is None:
        key = lambda x: x
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2
        if key(x) < key(a[mid]): hi = mid
        else: lo = mid+1
    return lo

>>> key=lambda r: r[1]
>>> insort(data, ('green', 3), key=key)
>>> bisect(data, 7, key=key) # error comparing tuple to int
```

Or alternatively

```
def insort(a, x, lo=0, hi=None, *, key=None):
    if key is None:
        key = lambda x: x
    lo = bisect(a, key(x), lo, hi, key)
    a.insert(lo, x)

def bisect(a, x, lo=0, hi=None, *, key=None):
    if lo < 0:
        raise ValueError('lo must be non-negative')
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(a)
    if key is None:
        key = lambda x: x
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2
        if x < key(a[mid]): hi = mid
        else: lo = mid+1
    return lo

>>> key=lambda r: r[1]
>>> item = ('green', 3)
>>> insort(data, item, key=key)
>>> bisect(data, item, key=key) # error comparing int to tuple
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Python 3.10, all the binary search helpers in the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) module accept a `key` argument. For example, the documentation on [`bisect_left`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left) contains this:

> *key* specifies a [key function](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-key-function) of one argument that is used to extract a
> comparison key from each element in the array. To support searching
> complex records, the key function is not applied to the *x* value.
>
> If key is `None`, the elements are compared directly with no intervening
> function call.

Thus, you can use this parameter similarly to `sorted()`. Just note that depending on the operation, the key function may not be applied to the value to be searched.